# How do you deal with long product titles on mobile?

Tags: product-design

I have a product card that only allows three lines of text and if it’s longer it adds an ellipsis. If you want to see the full text you just hover over and the tooltip will appear with the full text, pretty simple. The thing is that when you’re on mobile you can’t hover so what options would be good for cases like these where the text is too long?

Right now on mobile and desktop if you click on the title or anywhere inside the card it takes you directly to the product details.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14431411/5765312) with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the ellipses in the middle of the shortened string/texts rather than at the end. It is commonly the last portion of the string/texts that distinguishes it from others, so by putting the ellipses in the middle, you are not truncating the useful part of the string/texts which is usually the start of the end of the entire text.